# TypeScript compiler API - ts.createSourceFile doesn't error on invalid JS/TS files

Tags: typescript

I am using `ts.createSourceFile()` to parse an input JS/TS file and analyze its AST. At the moment even if I pass it invalid JS, it will still do a best effort and construct an AST.

I'd like to error on invalid input, but this function doesn't have such options. Is there any other API I can use to error on an invalid source?